# How does g++/gcc determine which library to link having more than 1 version to choose from?

Tags: c++, gcc, ld, dynamic-linking, devtoolset

I have installed devtoolset-3 on RHEL6 machine and I am confused by how gcc/g++ determines which library to link with a binary.

Standard setup on RHEL6:

```
$ g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada --enable-java-awt=gtk --disable-dssi --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-1.5.0.0/jre --enable-libgcj-multifile --enable-java-maintainer-mode --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --disable-libjava-multilib --with-ppl --with-cloog --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=i686 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11) (GCC)
```

After I compile a simple, nearly empty C++ binary I get:

```
$ g++ main.cpp -o main_old && ldd main_old
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffe6dfe000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00000039b4800000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00000039aa800000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00000039b4400000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00000039aa400000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00000039aa000000)
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin/:/bin/:/sbin
$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Then I would install `devtoolset-3` (from here https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/devtoolset-3/)

and then

```
$ scl enable devtoolset-3 bash
$ g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.9.1/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr --mandir=/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr/share/man --infodir=/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --enable-multilib --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto --enable-plugin --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-initfini-array --disable-libgcj --with-isl=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.9.1-20140922/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/isl-install --with-cloog=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.9.1-20140922/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/cloog-install --with-mpc=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.9.1-20140922/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/mpc-install --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=i686 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.1 20140922 (Red Hat 4.9.1-10) (GCC)
$ g++ main.cpp -o main_new && ldd main_new
       linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffe18ae000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00000039b4800000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00000039aa800000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00000039b4400000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00000039aa400000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00000039aa000000)
$ echo $PATH
/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr/bin/:/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin/:/bin/:/sbin
$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr/lib64:/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr/lib
```

I get the same...

Comment: Did you use g++ of the newly installed devtoolset?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GCC does not choose, per se. While GCC (actually `ld`) will find and examine dynamic libraries when linking (by its own path search order), it merely adds a `DT_NEEDED` entry for the library's `SONAME`. Take a look at the `DYNAMIC` section with `readelf`.

At runtime, `ld.so` chooses which library to link against. The particular library which `ld.so` selects is determined by its configured path search order. See the man page for `ld.so`.

Comment: Can I somehow manipulate this by editing some environment variables? I know I can add a path to new `gcc`'s libs in `/etc/ld.so.conf` but then I would need to remove it afterwards and env variables are easier to manipulate. **EDIT** even that didn't work :/

Comment: Check out the man page for `ld.so`. You'll see where `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` shows up in the search order (hint: it's very early).  If you want to use it when executing a program, I recommend doing it on the same line, so it doesn't affect the rest of your environment, like this: `$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/my/libs ./my_program`